# POST http://localhost:3000/addProjectTask/api/backlog/id09 404 (Not Found)

Tags: javascript, reactjs, spring-boot, rest

Trying to go from my one react component to another while performing this by using react-router dom in my app url get extended with router elements that we are using for this and not able to fetch my data from back-end.

Please help me on this. Actually because of this type of routing my api path is going like this `/projectBoard/api/backlog/id09`  instead of `api/backlog/id09` to fetch data.

what i have for now:
    **App.js:**

```
class App extends Component {
  render(){
  return (
    <Provider store={store}>
    <Router>
    <div className="App">
      <Header/>
      {/* <DashBoard/> */}
      <Route exact path="/dashboard" component={DashBoard}/>
      <Route exact path="/projectBoard/:id" component={ProjectBoard}/>
      {/*here we r trying to route our component*/}
      <Route exact path="/addProjectTask/:id" component={AddProjectTask}/>
      <Route exact path="/updateProjectTask/:backlog_id/:pt_id" component= 
      {UpdateProjectTask}/>
    </div>
    </Router>
    </Provider>
  );
}
}

export default App;

**ProjectBoard.js:**
 class ProjectBoard extends Component {
     //constructor to handle errors
     constructor(){
         super();
         this.state={
             errors:{}
         };
     }
     componentDidMount(){
         const {id}=this.props.match.params;
        // const {addProjectTask}=this.props.match.params;
         this.props.getBacklog(id)
     }
     componentWillReceiveProps(nextProps){
         if(nextProps.errors){
             this.setState({errors: nextProps.errors});
         }
     }

    render() {
        const {id}=this.props.match.params;
        const {project_tasks}=this.props.backlog;
        const {errors}=this.state;
        //const {project_tasks}
        let BoardContent;
        const boardAlgorithm=(errors,project_tasks)=>{
            if(project_tasks.length< 1){
                if(errors.projectNotFound){
                    return(
                        <div className="alert alert-danger text-center" 
                                role="alert">
                        {errors.projectNotFound}
                    </div>
                    );
                }
                    else{
                        return(
                            <div className="alert alert-danger text-center" 
                             role="alert">
                                No project Tasks on this board
                            </div>
                        );

                    }    

            }else{
                return (<Backlog project_tasks_prop={project_tasks}/>);
            }
        };
        BoardContent=boardAlgorithm(errors,project_tasks);

        return (
            <div>

    <div className="container">
        <Link to={`/addProjectTask/${id}`} className="btn btn-primary mb-3">
            <i className="fas fa-plus-circle"> Create Project Task</i>
        </Link>
        <br />
        <hr />
        {/* <!-- Backlog STARTS HERE --> */}
        {BoardContent}

    </div>

    {/* <!-- PROJECT BOARD ENDS HERE -->
    <!-- Spring Boot / React Students please ignore below --> */}

            </div>
        )
    }
}
ProjectBoard.propTypes={
    backlog:PropTypes.object.isRequired,
    getBacklog:PropTypes.func.isRequired,
    errors:PropTypes.object.isRequired
};

const mapStateToProps=state=>({
    backlog: state.backlog,
    errors:state.errors
});

export default connect(mapStateToProps,{getBacklog}) (ProjectBoard);

**backlogActions.js:**

export const getBacklog=backlog_id=>
async dispatch=>{
    try{
        const res=await axios.get(`api/backlog/${backlog_id}`);
        console.log("api test",res);
        dispatch({
            type:GET_BACKLOG,
            payload:res.data
        })
    }catch(err){
        dispatch({
            type:GET_ERRORS,
            payload:err.response.data
        });

    }


};
```

Comment: Use /api/ instead of api/

Comment: @Lemmy thaku this is working fine now.